# Loading Json in Store to display it on List Sencha Touch 2 jsonp

Tags: sencha-touch-2, jsonp, store

This is my model

```
Ext.define("StockWatch.model.Market", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    idProperty: 'CompanyCode',
    fields: [
        { name: 'CompanyCode', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'LastTradedPrice', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PercentageDiff', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'FiftyTwoWeekHigh', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'FiftyTwoWeekLow', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'ChangePercent', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Change', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'MarketCap', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'High', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Low', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PrevClose', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'OpenInterest', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'MarketLot', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'ChangeInOpenInterest', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'LastTradedTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' },
    ]
}
});
```

this is my store

```
Ext.define("StockWatch.store.Markets", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ["Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage", "Ext.data.proxy.JsonP", "StockWatch.model.Market"],
    config: {
        model: "StockWatch.model.Market",
        autoLoad : true,
        proxy : {
            type : 'jsonp',
            url : 'http://money.rediff.com/money1/current_status_new.php?companylist=17023928%7C17023929&id=1354690151&Rand=0.6305125835351646',
            reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:''
                }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not able to get the data on to my list, may be somewhere fetching of data is wrong.
guide me to find the solution.
also I'm using pull to refresh list plugin, so will the data be loaded automatically each time i pull down the list or do i have to write something over there to??

thnx in advance

**EDIT:** 
I also get this warning in the console

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://money.rediff.com/money1/current_status_new.php?companylist=17023928%7C17023929&id=1354690151&Rand=0.6305125835351646&_dc=1355822361093&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1".
```

Answer (score 1):

use [callbackKey](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-property-callbackKey)

callbackKey: Specifies the GET parameter that will be sent to the server containing the function name to be executed when the request completes. Defaults to callback. Thus, a common request will be in the form of url?callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1

Defaults to: "callback"

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the JSON response in a callback function for JSONP. It doesn't look like your remote call is returning this, try specifying a callback parameter - otherwise if the remote server does not allow this you need to pass it through another server to wrap it in a callback function.

Also, the warning you mentioned in the bottom of your post, don't worry about that. It won't cause any problems.